# Display hostname of DHCP client devices (option 12) in local intranet

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hostname, dhcp

this is my first question, so please don't be too hard with me. I really used the search functionality hard and also tried some stuff.

**Problem:**
Our .NET windows application communicates with our embedded measurement instrument via TCP/IP. Right now,
we use static IPs for our devices. When we ship our instrument (in conjunction with the PC software), the customer often needs to establish a peer to peer connection in order to change the static IP-address of our device in the first place. This can be really annoying and is not Plug&Play like.

**Intended solution:**
At device side we can enable DHCP mode, so the device's IP address will be assign by the customers network DHCP server.

Our plan was to scan local network and display all device with its IP address and the associated device hostname. The customer then selects the right device. Unfortunately we cannot manage to display the DHCP Option 12 (hostname) which is sent by the device during DHCP configuration.
We used **Wireshark** to validate that the device is acting correctly and sends its hostname with DHCP option 12.

Also we tried to use some third party tools ("MyLanViewer") in order to scan the local intranet and display all devices with its names. Our instrument is recognized, but the name is marked with "N/A"

**Approaches:**
We used the **IpHlpApi.dll** to use `GetIpNetTable`. This works fine and we get all IP addresses available in local scope. But when we want to read the `IPHostEntry` of the associated IP-address of our instrument, the `Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddressOfOurDevice)` throws an exception "*The host is unknown*".

The host names of windows based DHCP clients / computers can be read easily.

We also thought about implementing SSDP at device side. Problem is, the used TCP/IP stack does not support incoming multicast (which is mandatory).

Has anyone an idea how to read the DHCP Option 12 of any IP-address using windows APIs?

**Update:**
We're going to update our TCP/IP driver which shell be able to join SSDP multicast group in the most recent version. So our instrument will hopefully be recognized by any scanning application.

On application side we're going to use the RDSSP nuget package to discover all devices on the local network.

Comment: The handling of option 12 (hostname) is implementation dependent. On the DHCP server side: the server may store the hostname or to use it to identify the client. On the DHCP client side: the client may change the device name.You are refering to a use case in which the DHCP server needs to do something with the client supplied hostname. My suggestion: You need to find out what DHCP server it is and what it does with the hostname. Maybe the DHCP server offers an interface

Comment: @urutech: thanks for your hints. I'm going to see if I can get more information about the server. Unfortunately we need a solution which works in most cases (meaning for most DHCP servers). We hoped the option 12 (host name) is used by default, independent of the server type.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this example provides code you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dhcp/dhcp-client-api-examples#example-1-using-the-dhcprequestparams-function

You can use https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32 to create PInvoke stubs.

`Dns.GetHostEntry` uses `DNS` (not `DHCP`), but on Windows it also includes `NetBIOS`, that's the reason why you can resolve only Windows clients.

---

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32 --prerelease`

```
// NativeMethods.txt contents
DhcpRequestParams
DhcpCApiInitialize
DhcpCApiCleanup
OPTION_HOST_NAME
OPTION_SUBNET_MASK
OPTION_ROUTER_ADDRESS
DHCPCAPI_REQUEST_SYNCHRONOUS
WIN32_ERROR
BOOL
FALSE
TRUE
inet_ntoa
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Win32.Foundation;
using Windows.Win32.Networking.WinSock;
using Windows.Win32.NetworkManagement.Dhcp;
using static Windows.Win32.PInvoke;
using static Windows.Win32.Foundation.BOOL;
using static Windows.Win32.Foundation.WIN32_ERROR;

if (!OperatingSystem.IsWindowsVersionAtLeast(5, 1)) // XP
    return;

unsafe
{
    uint version;
    if (DhcpCApiInitialize(&version) != (uint)NO_ERROR)
        Environment.Exit(1);
    Console.WriteLine($"DHCP Client Version: {version}");
}

foreach (var name in new[]
         {
             // you can get this via `Get-NetAdapter | % DeviceID`
             "{ABCDEFED-1234-5678-9101-12345678986A}"
         })
{
    var str = RetrieveHostName(name);
    ShowAddrInfo(name); // show network info to verify that it actually works
    Console.WriteLine($"HostName='{str}'");
}

DhcpCApiCleanup();

// based on https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/dhcp/dhcprequest/dhcprequest.cpp
static unsafe void ShowAddrInfo(string pszAdapterName)
{
    DHCPAPI_PARAMS[] requests =
    {
        new()
        {
            Flags = 0,
            OptionId = OPTION_SUBNET_MASK,
            IsVendor = FALSE,
            Data = null,
            nBytesData = 0
        }, // subnet mask
        new()
        {
            Flags = 0,
            OptionId = OPTION_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
            IsVendor = FALSE,
            Data = null,
            nBytesData = 0
        } // gateway address
    };

    // set-up the actual arrays
    DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY sendarray = new()
    {
        nParams = 0, Params = null
    }; // we aren't sending anything

    // buffer variables
    uint dwSize = 8; // size of buffer for options
    byte[]? buffer; // buffer for options
    IN_ADDR addr = new(); // address in return code

    // loop until buffer is big enough to get the data and then make request
    WIN32_ERROR dwResult;
    fixed (DHCPAPI_PARAMS* Params = requests)
    {
        DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY requestarray = new()
        {
            nParams = 2, Params = Params
        }; // we are requesting 2
        fixed (char* wszAdapter = pszAdapterName)
            do
            {
                // requests[*].Data points inside buffer, so this should be pinned
                buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>((int)dwSize, pinned: true);
                dwResult = (WIN32_ERROR)DhcpRequestParams(DHCPCAPI_REQUEST_SYNCHRONOUS,
                    null,
                    wszAdapter,
                    null, sendarray,
                    requestarray,
                    (byte*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref buffer[0]), &dwSize,
                    null);
            } while (dwResult == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
    }

    // parse out results
    if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // first check subnet
        if (requests[0].nBytesData > 0)
        {
            Unsafe.Copy(ref addr, requests[0].Data /*, 4*/);
            Console.Write("Subnet Mask: {0}\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Subnet Mask NOT present!\n");

        // check for router address
        if (requests[1].nBytesData > 0)
        {
            Unsafe.Copy(ref addr, requests[1].Data /*, 4*/);
            Console.Write("Gateway Address: {0}\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Gateway Address NOT present!\n");

        GC.KeepAlive(buffer); // requests[*].Data points inside buffer, so this should be kept alive
    }
    else
        throw new Win32Exception((int)dwResult);
}

static unsafe string? RetrieveHostName(string pszAdapterName)
{
    var DhcpApiHostNameParams = new DHCPAPI_PARAMS
    {
        Flags = 0, // Flags
        OptionId = OPTION_HOST_NAME, // OptionId
        IsVendor = FALSE, // vendor specific?
        Data = null, // data filled in on return
        nBytesData = 0 // nBytes
    };
    var RequestParams = new DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY
    {
        nParams = 1, // only one option to request
        Params = &DhcpApiHostNameParams
    };

    var SendParams = new DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY
    {
        nParams = 0, Params = null
    };
    WIN32_ERROR dwError;
    // requests[*].Data points inside buffer, so this should be pinned
    byte[] buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>(1024, pinned: true);
    uint dwSize = (uint)buffer.Length;
    fixed (char* wszAdapter = pszAdapterName)
        dwError = (WIN32_ERROR)DhcpRequestParams(
            DHCPCAPI_REQUEST_SYNCHRONOUS, // Flags
            null, // Reserved
            new PWSTR(wszAdapter), // Adapter Name
            null, // not using class id
            SendParams, // sent parameters
            RequestParams, // requesting params
            (byte*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref buffer[0]), // buffer
            &dwSize, // buffer size
            null // Request ID
        );

    if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == dwError)
        throw new Win32Exception((int)dwError);

    if (NO_ERROR == dwError)
    {
        // Check if the requested option was obtained.
        if (DhcpApiHostNameParams.nBytesData != 0)
        {
            var ret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DhcpApiHostNameParams.Data, (int)DhcpApiHostNameParams.nBytesData);
            GC.KeepAlive(buffer); // requests[*].Data points inside buffer, so this should be kept alive
            return ret;
        }
        return null;
    }
    throw new Win32Exception((int)dwError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it. The PInvoke tool looks nice. Saves lots of time.

Comment: Spent some time using tools to simplify PInvoke stuff. Unfortunately many project are not maintained anymore. 

I ended up using the Vanara libraries. The libraries seem to work but I'm still too stupid to obtain the hostname (option 12) of a specific IP address. Honestly, I don't see a way using the dhcp-client api to manage that.

Comment: @Pille I added example, but as you figured out by yourself DHCP doesn't provide API to request information about **another** client. This can be *easily* worked around by opening socket in RAW mode and spoofing your IP.

Comment: @Pille also in my understanding option 12 works in another way. It allows DHCP server to set client hostname (`/etc/hostname`) on client.

Comment: I guess you're probably right. But some sources state that this option can be seen as bi-directional. On the other hand the device->server way seems not be working. Where as I managed to sent the host name from device to server, which I have verified with wireshark. Obviously the server doesn't care.